# How do I resolve data range failure from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, database, data-transfer

When refreshing a data source in Excel 2013, I get an error about a data range. How do I stop this error from occurring?

I think that the error has something to do with removing connections because it shows an error message stating that refreshing data will fail.

Image of error:   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the DATA tab, there is an icon labelled "Connections". If you click on that, you get a list of connections and you can delete the one called `evec_api_map`.

Comment: Thats the issue it IS deleted but i get this error message

Comment: In that case, you need to look at your named ranges and delete the one that contained the connection. Alternatively, if the workbook is relatively straight-forwards, create a new one and copy over the things you need one at a time saving in between and testing before saving to find which range causes it.

Comment: I know were the ranges are but i have put new date imports over them, so there gone.

Comment: Then something is messed up internally and I think you will have to resort to creating a new workbook as outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah thats what I've started doing. Is there a button which removes the dependency from the original workbook? Because if you copy and paste in data from one book to another and you have cells which get data from other sheets it adds [book1.xlsx] to the front of the query. I've Been removing it manually but it sucks :(

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me was to delete the XML connection.

In the Developer tab, Source->XML Maps (bottom right)->Delete